# How to clear react dropzone file input as well success icon and show initial drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I need to clear the file name as well success message once the file is uploaded . it should show the original label,as for there are two states used one for keeping track of the files (setFile()) and another one for errorstatus (setErrorStatus(false)).
There should be a way to clear the existing state and re render the initial states once clear button is clicked.

```
      export interface MyDropZone extends Dropzonezprops {
    
       onChange?: ( acceptedFiles :File[])=>void;
    }
    const MyDropzone : FC<MyDropZone>M= (props: MyDropZone) => {
    const[file,setFile]=React.usestate<null | File[]>(initialstate:null);
    const[errorStatus, setErrorstatus=React.usestate(false);
    const onDropAccepted=usecallback(async accepetdfiles => {
    ...
    setFile(accepetdfiles)
    if(!response.ok)
    setErrorstatus(true);
    }, []);
    
    return(
    <Box
        {!!file ? (
        <p>
        {uploaderrorstatus ? (
        <Icon icon = {'Close'} color= "danger"/>)
        : (
        <Icon icon = {'Checkmark'} color= "success"/>)}
        {file.map((file: File) => file.name).join(",")}
        </p>
        :<p> {"Drag and drop"}
        )}
</Box>
);
};
```

Comment: After the dropzone POST request has finished, simply call `setFile(null)` and `setErrorStatus(false)`

Comment: this just clear the file, i want to show the drag and drop label again ,on clear

Comment: Hm, can you create a [mre]?

Comment: any other way out ?

Comment: What exactly is the drag and drop label?

Comment: yes so basically i want to add some clear callback kind which will remove the icon for error ans sucess and set the label to Drag and Drop again just back to its initial form

Comment: Looking at your JSX, shouldn't the text appear when all involved state is set back to its original value?

Comment: so the clear button is outside of this componenent ,what will be the implementation  of the clear callback here ,will it be func or a callback

Comment: If you're asking how to have two siblings communicate, the solution is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: what i am asking where i will set setFile(null) and setStaus(false), this is a component and another component of mine which is using this component  ,so my seconnd component want to re render this component on clear